# Naming a text file with a date and time parameter + a string

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

in my project I have to encrypt some notes of patients what i do is I get the "LocalDateTime dateTime" through a parameter and create a file with that name + "Encryptedtxt" + ".txt". And additionally I wanted to add the doctors id too but first of all I need to do the first part. So i attempted the task but it's not working as I'm expecting. This is the part where I'm creating the file,

```
    public void txtEncrypt(String text, LocalDateTime localDateTime) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        try {

            String subfolder = "Encryption" + File.separator + "txt";
            String fileName = localDateTime + "-encryptedText.txt";
            File file = new File(subfolder, fileName);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

This only works partially. This is the output

[image: This only adds the localDate time "-encryptedText.txt" is missing]

This only adds the localDate time ".  -encryptedText.txt" is missing.
Can someone kindly help me out in this one?

Comment: Is this code running on Windows by any chance? Colons aren't allowed in Windows filenames (as they're used for drive letters). I strongly suspect that your `fileName` variable is something like "2023-01-31T12:34:56.123-encryptedText.txt". You need to decide what *valid* filename you want to use instead. (You could just remove the colons, for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use local date time object directly in file name, it will give you text value like - 2023-01-07T14:38:00.502959700 so you can't create file name with colon(:) in it.

You need to format your local date time object in any permissible format then it will work. You can try below code -

```
    String subfolder = "Encryption" + File.separator + "txt";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss");
    String fileName = localDateTime.format(formatter) + "-encryptedText.txt";
    File file = new File(subfolder, fileName);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: True, you can change date pattern as per your choice, with valid symbols for file name.

Comment: This worked! tysm!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call dateFormat.format(localDateTime), or something like that, and get an string to add to the "-encryptedText.txt", to sum up, you need to add an string to another string, you can not add a string to an object

Answer (score -1):

HH:mm:ss is invaild for filename,so this filename is filtered